# iPhone Application Tracking through Google Analytics

Tags: iphone, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I have implemented the new Google Analytics tracking in my iPhone app and I can see the data in my Google Analytics reporting screen.

However, I want to extract this data and display it on my site using the Core Reporting API.  I get the page views for my site using the ga:pagePath filter on the Visits metric.  I can't however find any documentation about how I would extract the Screens data from the report.  Has anyone found any?

Ideally I would like to filter the Screens by Screen Name and get the number of views. The only metric I have found is ga:appviews which returns my total number of appViews so do i filter the screen Name on this and how would I do that?

Thanks for any help you can offer!

Paul

Answer (score 0):

I think google just forgot the ga:screenName which they should have created in:

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/dimsmets/apptracking#ga:uniqueAppviews

Answer (score 0):

ga:screenViews is working well now ! :-)

you have also : ga:screenName and ga:uniqueScreenViews